# MassTransit: is there a way to log income messages

Tags: .net, masstransit

I'd like to log every message that i consume in MassTransit. Is there a way to implement global interceptor where i could handle income message or achieve that using configuration?

My current config looks like this:

```
BusFactory = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(AppSettings.RmqConnectionString), h => { });

    cfg.UseNLog();

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RmqPropertyKeys.CallbackQueue, e=> e.LoadFrom(container));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation includes an example middleware filter which does exactly that, logs on every message that is delivered to a consumer.

http://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/custom.html

You can also use the built-in `LogFilter` if you like:

```
cfg.UseLog(Console.Out, (context,logContext) => $"Format your log message");
```

Comment: could you please provide your answer with an example of logging using NLog? Ty

Comment: I can't figure out how can i access message content (for example, i'd like to log every message content that i consume in custom middleware).

Comment: You'd have to create a logger for each message type, and register those individually on each message type. Then the context is passed to the filter.

Comment: Or you could just use a `ConsumeObserver` that would observe each message after it is consumed, and use the generic type on the method to resolve and invoke a log formatter for that message.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use `ConsumeObserver`.

Implement the interface IConsumeObserver:

```
public class ConsumeObserver : IConsumeObserver
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsumeObserver> _logger;

    public ConsumeObserver(ILogger<ConsumeObserver> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task ConsumeFault<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
        //use _logger

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task PostConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        //use _logger

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task PreConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        //use _logger

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then connect your observer:

```
busControl.ConnectConsumeObserver(consumeObserver);
```