# How should be initialized CorrelationId at MassTransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'd like to track my messages using built-in interface `CorrelatedBy<TKey>`, but i didn't quite understand: should i initialize it myself, for example, in constructor of my message (command)?

```
public class RegisterCallback : IRegisterCallback
{
    public RegisterCallback()
    {
        CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize it by either passing it into the constructor, or otherwise generating it as part of the constructor.

```
public RegisterCallback(Guid correlationId) {...}
```

Or you can generate it using `NewId` to get an ordered identifier.

```
public RegisterCallback()
{
    CorrelationId = NewId.NextGuid();
}
```

Also, your interface should include `CorrelatedBy<Guid>` if you want to use the built-in support.

```
public interface IRegisterCallback :
    CorrelatedBy<Guid> {...}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Chris. Could you please help with next question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706284/masstransit-is-there-a-way-to-log-income-messages) ?

Comment: @Chris When using `CorrelatedBy<Guid>` what is meant by "built-in support"? I rekon, MassTransit will populate `CorrelationId` property of the `ConsumeContext` with the value of a `CorrelationId` from the message, right?

Comment: Yeah, it should if the property is called CorrelationId and is a Guid.